# batch processing files and using the filename of the files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, batch-processing

I have a folder ('d:\0 DATA\') with some text-files (AA.txt, AB.txt, F.txt, GA.txt, HAB.txt, ....).
In the folder, I have added a file 'c:\0 DATA\index.txt' with the names of the files (AA, AB, F, GA, HAB...) in separate lines.

I want to read every file and do some calculations. The file-name without txt should be in a variable to be useable as an output.

This is the current code with manual file selection:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbolabr = 'AB'
filesource1 = 'D:\\0 DATA\\' + symbolabr + '.txt'
qt = pd.read_csv(filesource1)

...

np.savetxt(symbolabr + '_result.csv', calculatedvar)
```

How can I change this to batch-processing all files in the folder and get an output for every of those files?

Comment: You read a line from `index.txt`, assign the label to `symbolabr`, and continue with your current code.  Wrap all of that in a loop while there are lines available in `index.txt`.  If you need help coding a "read all lines" loop, see any of the many tutorials on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do this

```
import glob

filesource1 = glob.glob("D:\\0 DATA\\*.txt"): #get all text files 
for f in filesource1 : #do something  same for each file
    print("Processing File : "+ f)
    qt = pd.read_csv(f)

    ...

    np.savetxt(f.split("\\")[-1].split('.')[0] + '_result.csv', calculatedvar)
```

Comment: that gives this error: 
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

Comment: thank you. problem is, it now only processes the last file in the folder. And how can I get only the filename (for example "BA") in a variable?

Comment: this (`f.split("\\")[-1].split('.')[0] `) will give you only file name without .txt

Comment: its still the problem, that it only processes the last file of the folder

Comment: I have added a print please share the output of the program ? also make sure you are copying the code from here as it is

Comment: print shows all files, but after read_csv only the last file (YM.txt) is processed

Comment: that is indentation issue please move  this line `np.savetxt(f.split("\\")[-1].split('.')[0] + '_result.csv', calculatedvar)` under for loop this line is causing the issue i thinks so rather move all your code under for loop